# How to fix issue while using Dhru API with PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json

I am using DHRU API in PHP and JSON. I am using this code to store the values of DHRU API in $request variable

```
$request = $api->action('accountinfo');
```

Well these values are perfectly stored in $request variable but besides that it is also printing the values as shown below. I don't want to display these values, i just want to store it in $request variable,

```
{"SUCCESS":[{"message":"Your Accout Info","AccoutInfo":  
{"credit":"1USD","mail":"abc.com","currency":"USD"}}],"apiversion":"2.0.0"}
```

Comment: just decode it and pick which index you want and just echo it

Comment: I am using this syntax for decoding:  $request = json_decode($api->action('accountinfo'), true);                  But then i am getting the error "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\......"

Comment: use `print_r($api->action('accountinfo'));` then. it says array given. you'll get to see what the contents are, then just call the contents using `echo $request['index name here']; ...`

Comment: Although this line of code is not showing the warning but it is still printing the whole contents as mentioned above:  $request = json_decode(print_r($api->action('accountinfo')), true);

Answer (score 0):

You could go ahead and capture the output buffer.

```
ob_start();
$api->action('accountinfo');
$request = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Since you don't actually care about the contents, this will stop the function from printing when called.

Comment: I used your code then it works fine and did not display anything but now i am using loop and it shows me the "Warning: Illegal string offset 'SUCCESS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testcopy.php on line 38" foreach($request[SUCCESS] as $p)
{
echo 'Message: '.$p["message"]. '</br>';
}